# -bash: /usr/local/bin/nmap: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, catalina

I recently update my Mac OS to Catalina 10.15.

I ran `nmap` I kept getting

> `-bash: /usr/local/bin/nmap: Bad CPU type in executable`

---

I've tried reinstalling it

```
brew uninstall nmap
brew install nmap
```

but I see no effect, I even try full path

```
⚡️  Desktop  which nmap 
/usr/local/bin/nmap
⚡️  Desktop  /usr/local/bin/nmap
-bash: /usr/local/bin/nmap: Bad CPU type in executable
⚡️  Desktop
```

Comment: What's the result of `file /usr/local/bin/nmap`? Get the 64bit version if you detect a *Mach-O executable i386*.

Comment: @klanomath : I ran the command above, I got this `/usr/local/bin/nmap: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: If you think brew is the issue, try `brew reinstall --verbose nmap` and are you sure you don’t have another binary in your $PATH

Comment: I install the actual `.dmg` from the site, seems working now.

Comment: Thank-you guys for your willingness to help .

Comment: Awesome! Ask again if you need more help with other brew

Comment: manually install rosetta helped me
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to go the site :

https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html

[image]

Click on **Download**

https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.80.dmg

I downloaded that .dmg, installed it, now my nmap working again.

[image]

> **Note** : I will leave this post since, it might help others in the future.

Comment: thank you for this answer! side question: after updating to 10.15, i had issues with python and now nmap.... does anyone know why in general these issues are being caused? is 10.15 breaking almost everything for devs?

Comment: You’re welcome. Please ask and add details.

Comment: Installing the latest version worked for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find this to be an x86 (32bit) vs x64 problem, thus a new version will be required.