# zsh: bad CPU type in executable

Tags: terminal, zsh, apple-silicon

I am using the terminal on an Apple M1 MacBook. I try to use a cli tool that is not build for aarm64, so I get this error message in the terminal:

```
zsh: bad CPU type in executable
```

Is there anything I can do to use this cli tool e.g. with emulation or something? How can I run binaries on a M1 based Mac in the Terminal that is not natively built for Arm?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

When macOS tries to run an app that is not built for Apple silicon, macOS will prompt to install Rosetta 2 to automatically translate the app to Apple silicon.

In Terminal, there is no automatic detection for missing Rosetta to run older architecture command line tools.

If you haven't been prompted for any other app already, manually install [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861):

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

If you need to run a universal binary in the previous architecture, use `arch` and specify the architecture. You need to manually specify the architecture for binaries that need to run other binaries that are not built for Apple silicon, like Homebrew.

```
arch -x86_64 …
```

e.g. `arch -x86_64 brew install packagename`

Alternatively, you can run the entire Terminal app using Rosetta by opening Get Info on Terminal.app in Finder and checking ‘Open using Rosetta’. This way will Terminal and every binary it tries to run through Rosetta, so Apple silicon binaries won't be supported and performance will be impacted, but you don't need to specify the architecture to run old binaries.

To switch an existing zsh terminal to x86_64 use this command:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
```

Comment: Is there no support for something like `binfmt` in Linux?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Even `binfmt` needs handlers for the different formats. Installing Rosetta will add the functionality required to run Intel code on M1.

Comment: @nohillside Sure you need the handler, but `binfmt` makes sure the check happens right in the `exec` call, so it doesn't matter if you start a foreign-architecture program from the GUI, the terminal, a script, or another binary.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev What makes you think it works otherwise on macOS (even if the kernel functions are called differently)? Unless Rosetta is installed, Big Sur/M1 can't execute Intel code. Once it is, the OS will pick the right binary automatically, the `arch` command can be used to override that (as can the checkbox in Finder).

Comment: I am getting the same error (zsh: bad CPU type in executable)  when I run the command `arch -x86_64 zsh` (I have installed rosetta)

Comment: I just ran into this problem with asdf instead of nvm. I got the same issue with `arch -x86_64 zsh` on two computers but not with `arch -x86_64 asdf install nodejs 14.17.4` - that ran fine.

Comment: Interestingly, it worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @SametBaskıcı - you might want to refer the exact path towards your zsh binary `arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh`

Answer (score 3):

If you are running:
`arch -x86_64 zsh`
(or similar) and get this error, try running

```
which -a zsh
```

to check your zsh installations. I ended up with

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh
/bin/zsh
```

and needed to

```
brew uninstall zsh
```

to get just one, then the arch command worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

If you are facing this error when installing Homebrew on mac. Follow these steps:

1. Open a new Terminal session.
2. Remove `/usr/local/bin` from PATH for this session by `PATH=${PATH/\/usr\/local\/bin:}`
3. Run `which git curl` in this session.
4. Confirm that you get no errors and neither path reported begins with `/usr/local/bin`
5. Run the installer in this session.

Source: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1379#discussioncomment-672727

Comment: The question is about the error message in general, not about installing Homebrew on an M1 installation migrated from Intel.

Comment: added details for if Homebrew install has problem then follow these steps.