# Ping got killed automatically under Big Sur on M1 Mac Mini

Tags: big-sur, ping

I received my M1 Mac Mini last week and it was wonderful.

However, today when I was trying to ping my other server, it got killed right away.

```
Walton@Waltons-Mac-Mini ~> ping
Killed: 9
```

Does any know what happened?

Comment: If you’re running `/sbin/ping` and it gets killed, the console app should show an error at the same time as you get the error.

Comment: `type ping`. If it isn't in `/sbin/ping`, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable might help

Comment: Thanks. Indeed my ping is not in /sbin/ping so I edit /etc/paths and chaged the order. Now it works :D