# zsh: bad CPU type in executable: ngrok

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

- I have a mac processor 1.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i3 and macOS Catalina
- I install ngrok AMD64 from the website https://ngrok.com/download
- I keep getting the error: zsh: bad CPU type in executable: ngrok

Existing answers do not help, any advice?

Comment: What answers?  If you check the binary with `file`, what is returned?

Comment: You also say “you install..from the website”. Can we assume you downloaded the binary?  Or, did you follow the Homebrew instructions?  Are you certain AMD64 was downloaded and not ARM64?

Comment: I downloaded the AMD64 binary from the website. I tried at some point with homebrew and that didn't work either. 

file ngrok returns: ngrok: MacOS Alias file. By existing answers I meant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable - I don't think this fits my case.

Comment: First, find out what location it's trying to run `ngrok` from with `type -a ngrok`. That should print one or more lines like "ngrok is /some/path/to/ngrok". For each one it prints, try `file /some/path/to/ngrok` (using the paths that `type` printed), and see what that says. If there's a correct one in your path, it'll be listed as "/some/path/to/ngrok: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64" If that doesn't tell you what you need to know, edit the results of all those commands into your question (in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361), so it displays accurately).

Comment: Thank you. Deleted the binary, tried following the homebrew instructions and it worked.